# How to refer to a cell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to update a label in a cell outside of

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

by using

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
```

in another function. However, I keep getting errors. Therefore, I tried to refer to the cell by using `let cell = Cell()`, but I get the error `unexpectedly found nil`. Lastly, I tried

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! Cell
```

that does not return an error, but the label `cell.time.text` is not updated.

Comment: Don't do that, **never** call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` outside of `cellForRow` . Update the value in the model (data source array) and reload the table view or the single row.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**  &  **Swift 4**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

**NOTE :-** With help of above method you can only get visible cell of `tableView` except cell is nil

Comment: Thank you. How would I write this in Swift 2.3?

Comment: Be aware that you will lose the changes when the user scrolls.

Comment: i had to add "let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! <cell class here>" on Swift 4

Comment: you can add on swit 4.0 @ttorbik

Comment: Make sure you declared `tableview` outlet and link the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of your `tableView`

Comment: @HarshalValanda How to access the cell once the cell is not visible and the user has scrolled it?

Comment: @vadian How to access the cell once it's not visible and the user has scrolled it?

Comment: @Saurabh A non-visible cell doesn't exist *physically*.

Comment: @vadian Any way to retain it or access the property of that cell?

Comment: @Saurabh A cell is just a view for the model. Get the information from the model.

Comment: @vadian I need cell property to check height and width of label with the dynamic font. I don't need any data from it But I should be able to access those Labels

Comment: As I said invisible cells are not accessible. Please ask a question and add details what you are going to accomplish.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use cell outside of the `UITableView` override method `cellForRowAt indexPath` then first of all, you need to fetch the `indexPath` of row and then using the `indexPath` of that row you can get the cell of `UITableView`.

Once, you get the cell then you can access their properties & methods outside of `UITableView`.

Try this:

In this code, i'm use a Custom Cell.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MembersCell
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Step1:

update the data of the model

#### Step2:

reload indexPath

```
 let indexPathToRefresh = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
 tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPathToRefresh], with: .none)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` outside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

You should use `cellForRow(at:)`
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as! CustomCell
```

If your cell has properties like

```
@IBOutlet label: UILabel!
```

you can use this:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as! CustomCell).label.text = "Test123" // smth like this
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Swift 2.3, could you please convert it to that?

Comment: @Dups idk change list 2.3 -> 3.1. But maybe it will use NSIndexPath instead of IndexPath.

Comment: If I convert to 3.1, I'll have to rewrite everything.

Comment: @Dups I mean you maybe should use NSIndexPath in your code instead of IndexPath (as I remember its swift 3.0 + version. Not sure)

Comment: @Dups Do the conversion. It's worth it and you will learn a lot about Swift. Most likely today Swift 4 will be introduced. Do you want to miss the boat?

Comment: @vadian today? Nice!

Comment: @VladPulichev Today is opening of WWDC 2017.

Comment: Nice and simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using touchUp inside targets. You might run into problems when scrolling fast and pressing buttons. You press one row button but when you release the finger that is another row button releasing the action. Also you might run into memory leaks. If you add a target you must remove it later! If you want to add targets it is better to use TouchDown event instead to avoid such problems. I personally use tapGestures. Then when the viewdisappear I find the cell which has a tapGesture and remove it for memory leaks issues.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.1 ++

Safe way to get custom cell refrence outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

Here is Code :

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
 
if let cell = self.yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? customCell {
       
     // Get all custom cell property refrence 
     // Do what ever you want ..
     
}
```

## Note:

You can get only visible cell refrence